# Remove Blurred Preview for ContextMenu on NavigationLink in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, contextmenu, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to add a `contextMenu` to a `NaviagationLink` in swiftUI. The result as you can see below is a blurred view is showing as a preview.

```
NavigationLink {
    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
} label: {
    Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
        .padding()
}
.contextMenu(
    ContextMenu {
        Button(action: {
            print("")
        }) {
            Label("Save", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
        }
    }
)


private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()
```

[image]

Comment: What does your `itemFormatter` code look like?

Comment: Have added ```itemFormatter``` code to the question

Answer (score 0):

I put together some example code to see if I could understand the problem. It's the underlying text in your view which gets blurred by the `ContextMenu` action. If the items are sufficiently spaced I am not seeing the blurring issue. Here is the code example I set up.

```
struct ItemWithTimeStamp: Identifiable, Hashable {
var id: UUID

let timestamp: Date
let name: String

}

struct ContentView: View {

let examples = [ItemWithTimeStamp(id: UUID(), timestamp: Date(), name: "Thing One"), ItemWithTimeStamp(id: UUID(), timestamp: Date(timeInterval: 1234, since: .now), name: "Thing Two"), ItemWithTimeStamp(id: UUID(), timestamp: Date(timeInterval: 6543, since: .now), name: "Thing Three")]


var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            ForEach(examples, id: \.id) { item in
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                } label: {
                    Text(item.timestamp, formatter: itemFormatter)
                        .padding()
                }
                .contextMenu(
                    ContextMenu {
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Saved")
                        }) {
                            Label("Save", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
                        }
                    }
                )

            }
        }
    }

}


private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()


}
```

This is the View before activating the context menu.

[image: raw dates]

Here I'm activating the ContextMenu and you can see the blurred text in the background. But in my case with standard `.padding()` between the items the overlap isn't happening so I'm not seeing the blurring issue as you're getting. But I'm not sure what the rest of your view looks like.

I don't know if it suits your purposes but you might try placing the NavigationLink's in a `List` as they are definitely separated out and will not overlap. Replace the `VStack` with `List` in my code to see an example of this.

[image: screen shot of context menu]